# get revisions by change_jd from gerrit api

Tags: gerrit

i want to get gerrit change files
from gerrit document,i need to use the api:

```
GET /changes/{change-id}/revisions/{revision-id}/files/
```

but i have the change-id,i cannot get the revisions by the changeid.

althougth ,the document said changeInfo entity has that info,
but i use

```
'GET /changes/{change-id}'
```

but it dose not contains revisions

so, how i can get the change`s revisionids,to find the change file？

or there has other method to get change files ?

thank you

Comment: i think add ?o=CURRENT_REVISION   can get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

{revision-id} could be 1, 2, etc or you can use "current" to match the latest patchset:

```
GET /changes/{change-id}/revisions/current/files/
```

See more info in the Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#revision-id)

Comment: thank you, i use  /changes/{change_id}?o=CURRENT_REVISION or ALL_REVISIONS can get the revisions. but i had a new question, i want to get the old code file or content, /changes/{change_id}/revisions/{revisons_id}/files/{file_name}/content  or download, actually, i can get the new code,not the old file content, can you help me? thank you

Comment: The optional, integer-valued parent parameter can be specified to request the named file from a parent commit of the specified revision. The value is the 1-based index of the parent’s position in the commit object. If the parameter is omitted or the value is non-positive, the patch set is referenced.   i think maybe this is a answer,but i am not sure,and i try failed

Comment: Did the answer work? It would be good accept it to let other users to know. You need  to create another question to this other issue.

Comment: it works,and other question has been solved，thank you